# how separate a string and a double values inside a square bracket using regex

Tags: c#

I want to separate a string and a double value which is inside a square bracket, using regex.

I tried the code just to separate the words inside the square brackets.

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(avatarVM.AvatarText, @"\[(.*?)\]");
```

In my code it displays only the words inside the square brackets. For example if this is the whole text [Hello : 2.5], I want separate "Hello" into a string and "2.5" into a double value using regex

Comment: I'd just use replace and then split

Comment: Can there ever be more than one key/value pair within the square brackets?

Comment: `s.Split(new[] { '[', ']', ':', ' ' },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`

Comment: or maybe `\[(\w*) : (\d*.?\d*)\]`

Answer (score 0):

`MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(avatarVM.AvatarText, @"\[(.*?)\ ?\:\ ?([\d]+\.?[\d]?)\]")` should work.

You'll then need to do a `double.Parse(matches[2].ToString())` to parse the double out of the match.

This also should work if there is no space before or after the colon. It will also work if the number doesn't have a decimal point.

Comment: Not that it was mentioned, what if the word has spaces?

Comment: @TheGeneral the regex is still good (i think) as .*? matches whitespace too. The colon is required as the delineation between the two values. I'm sure the regex could be improved as well. :)